# Running Sqitch to deploy a database in Postgres on a Docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, sqitch

I am running Postgres on a Docker container.

I have been trying to following the example show to deploy scripts using Sqitch from the
following page:

https://metacpan.org/pod/sqitchtutorial

Now I have got as far as creating my folders for Deploy, Revert and Verify

I then try to deploy changes using the following command:

```
sqitch deploy db:pg://username:password@localhost/flipr_test
```

where i pass in my username and password

However i get the following error message:

```
Adding registry tables to db:pg://postgres:@localhost/flipr_test
"/opt/local/pgsql/bin/psql" failed to start: "The system cannot find the path specified"
```

How can I get Sqitch to run to deploy a database to Postgres running on a Docker Container?

Comment: The issue is `/opt/local/pgsql/bin/psql` is not being found. Not clear to me where the Sqitch repo is on the host or in the Docker container?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Folowing the tutorial, the Sqitch repo is on my C drive in a folder called Flipr

Comment: As im running Postrgres on a Docker container, I dont know how to navigate to the path 
/opt/local/pgsql/bin/psql
Im completely new to Sqitch and not being using  Docker for that long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to do the following :

1. Get a Sqitch.bat file using the following command wget https://git.io/JTAi6 -o sqitch.bat
2. Copy this Sqitch.bat file into the flipr folder.

This sqitch file runs Sqitch in a Docker Container

3. Add the following line to docker-compose.yml for the Postgres Database (Under 'environment'):
   environment:

```
- POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
```

4. Then in  ~/.sqitch/sqitch.conf

Comment out the following line:

```
#client = /opt/local/pgsql/bin/psql
```

This means that psql will then be used from the Postgres container

5. Now I can run the following command

```
.\sqitch.bat deploy db:pg://postgres:password!@localhost/flipr_test
```

Here the sqitch.bat is running up Sqitch in the Docker Container and then from there can run the deploy command to deploy changes

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, just a long comment describing how to troubleshoot/fix this. Sqitch uses database native clients to connect to the respective engine. In the Postgres case that is `psql`. You need to have `psql` installed and accessible when you run Sqitch commands against the engine. As a for instance, in Ubuntu/Debian that would be installing the `postgresql-client` package. You have not mentioned what OS you are using so the install maybe different. The `psql` client would also need to be 'seen' by the `sqitch deploy` command wherever you are running that. You don't indicate where `sqitch deploy` is being run, on the Docker host or in the Docker container. In either case `psql` needs to be present at the path specified for the command run. In your case either `psql` is not installed or if installed it is at path other then `/opt/local/pgsql/bin/psql`. In the tutorial search for `sqitch config --user engine.pg.client` to see how you can change the path.

Comment: thank you for that. OK some progress made. I ran the command sqitch config --user engine.pg.client /opt/local/pgsql/bin/psql  

then tried to run my sqitch deploy command and now getting a new message 
Nothing to deploy(empty plan)
which i can now investigate

Im running Linux on the Docker container

Comment: If you have not done `sqitch add <some_change>` then  there will be nothing to deploy.  Read the [Tutorial](https://sqitch.org/docs/manual/sqitchtutorial/). You still have not said whether the Sqitch repo is located in the host file system or the Docker container file system.

Comment: The Squitch repo is located on the C drive of my PC in a git folder. Under this there are subfolders for deploy revert etc

Comment: Alright, but if you have not added any changes using `sqitch add` there will nothing in the sub-directories and  no entry in `sqitch.plan`. This means there will nothing to `deploy`.

Comment: I found a solution to this..you can see my answer.. but thank you very much for your help and advice on this.